# Label for input inside other label - is this correct

Tags: html, input, label

This is best illustrated with an example:

```html
<label for="myInput">This is an external label</label>

<br>

<label>
This label is wrapped arround the input
<input type="text" id="myInput">
</label>
```

Is this correct in HTML5? I understand multiple labels can point at one input field, but a label can only point at one field. In the example it are two labels pointing at the same input, only one is wrapping around the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct in HTML5?

Yes.

> I understand multiple labels can point at one input field, but a label
>   can only point at one field

Yes, again.

From the specs here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

> The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as
>   the label element's labeled control, either using the for attribute,
>   or by putting the form control inside the label element itself.

When there is no `for` attribute and the `label` is nested with its labelable control, then the first such descendant becomes its labelable control. But, a `label` should not be nested with other `label`s.

The `label.control` property returns the form control that is associated with this element. Vice-versa, `.labels` is a readonly property on labelable controls which return a `nodelist` of all applicable labels on that control.

**Example 1:**

*In the example below, the `input.labels` property returns a `nodeList` which contains both the labels.*

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('myInput');
console.log(inp.labels);
```

```html
<label for="myInput">This is an external label</label>
<br>
<label>
  This label is wrapped around 
  <input type="text" id="myInput">
</label>
```

---

**Example 2:**

*In this example, I have purposefully associated one label to two inputs. See that only the first one encountered i.e. with the `for` attribute here gets associated, and the second one is ignored even though it has a nested control.*

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput'), 
    yourInput = document.getElementById('yourInput')
;
console.log(myInput.labels);
console.log(yourInput.labels);
```

```html
<label for="myInput">
 This is an external label
 <input id="yourInput">
</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```